# angular-ui-router vs native $router performance comparison

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angular-ui-router

I am tasked to determine how migration from native angular $router to angular-ui-router will impact web application's performance.
It seems that there is no relevant material on the internet.
To my understanding routing should not impact web application performance much as majority of performance drop is related to $watches generated by directives (ng-repeat, etc) and ajax calls.
Additional questions to consider:

1. Would multiple nested views affect performance? Should I avoid multiple level nesting.
2. Would multiple views affect performance?

To rephrase the question to make it short and simple: Is it necessary to worry about performance drop after migrating from native $router to angular-ui-router provided everything else in the application stays same?

I believe migration of routing will not affect negatively performance.
Please, correct me if I am wrong. Any insights will be helpful.

Comment: And if nested views do affect performance, will you sacrifice your code composition, modularity, readability to gain some performance gain? Performance is one of those 80/20 issues - 80% of performance issues/gains are in 20% of the code. Anyway, you are right that number and speed of `$watchers` have arguably the biggest impact on performance in Angular. Also, DOM elements insertion and removal is a performance bottleneck, and each update of the View does that. But, unless you plan to change Views very rapidly, this shouldn't be a concern, and `ui-view` doesn't add any $watchers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In case of my application, there is not much of rerouting.It is rather navigation to the specific view responsible for certain component and continuous update of it's parameters by ajax calls, which means that first I reroute and only after it's done real performance prone action takes place.